# std::mutex vs std::recursive_mutex as class member

Tags: c++, c++11, mutex, object-design, recursive-mutex

I have seen some people hate on `recursive_mutex`:

http://www.zaval.org/resources/library/butenhof1.html

But when thinking about how to implement a class that is thread safe (mutex protected), it seems to me excruciatingly hard to prove that every method that should be mutex protected is mutex protected and that mutex is locked at most once.

So for object oriented design, should `std::recursive_mutex` be default and `std::mutex` considered as an performance optimization in general case unless it is used only in one place (to protect only one resource)?

To make things clear, I'm talking about one private nonstatic mutex. So each class instance has only one mutex.

At the beginning of each public method:

```
{
    std::scoped_lock<std::recursive_mutex> sl;
```

Comment: If it's excruciating to design your code properly then avoid mutexes altogether and use another form of synchronisation such as message queues. Using `recursive_mutex` not because you need it but just because you can't be bothered to get the locking correct is a hack. A dirty hack.

Comment: @JonathanWakely to quote STL: "I disagree in the strongest possible terms".. example I  think GC is a tradeoff because you trade perf for dont caring(lets ignore that you want RAII, lets think of hyphotetical C with GC vs C). Point here is that I want my member functions to be called one by one... and I dont care if one of them calls other... I want to free my mind to focus on more important stuff/be more productive. :)

Comment: Fine, you're free to do that. You asked "for OO design should std::recursive_mutex be default" and the answer is no. In the general case you should design your locking carefully or not do locking at all. If you can't be bothered, fine. That doesn't make it the correct default for the general case. But then you've already decided to discount the wisdom of Dave Butenhof and ask if you know better, so I'm not expecting you to like my advice.

Comment: @JonathanWakely please read the discussion in the Steves answer... point is that I see no point in ensuring that mtx is locked only once... except for perf reasons. Much simpler it is to just stick lock_guard as first line of every public method

Comment: I read it before commenting. It's a hack.

Comment: It makes it impossible to release the mutex (e.g. to use it to wait on a condition variable) temporarily because you have no idea if releasing the current scope's lock will completely release the mutex. It makes it difficult to do anything with two objects at once, e.g. copy assignment, that requires locking both. It can't work in the general case, only a very specific case of an entirely private mutex used in very simple ways.

Comment: @JonathanWakely I dont use condition variables(not fancy/modern enough for me) in my code, but that is a fair point. Regarding copy assignment I dont see how mtx vs rec_mtx help, if we talk about per instance mtx.

Comment: *"idk if they are good. Aka they seem too much "IMHO this""* - Of course they are (*"IMHO this"*, not good, well that too, but ok). All they can do is provide objective arguments why they are correct for their own objective reasons, which they do. You are of course entirely free to accept those arguments or have a different but nevertheless valid opinion on this. But likewise does this mean you probably won't get a *"better"* answer than *"Yeah, you're absolutely right, `std::recursive_mutex` is much better"*. But good question, of course.

Comment: The existing answers have the opinion that properly thinking about the details of your locking behaviour is a good thing, and using `std::mutex` exactly helps with that. You in turn don't want to think about the details of your locking and for that `std::recursive_mutex` is good. If you don't agree with the linked article, you most probably won't get conviced of the other answers' viewpoint. But ok, let's see what other answers the bounty attracts.

Comment: @ChristianRau - my point is that they provide no (IMO ofc) reasons why bad things happen if I just dont care in a same way I dont care how many bytes new MyObject() allocated or how many pointers per element std::set has(btw  I believe it is 3 :) )

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl Well, I think they do. There are a whole bunch of things that can go wrong if you don't know if locking or unlocking something really locks or unlocks it (or silently does just nothing), like e.g. deadlocks in the presence of condition variables and the like. You then say *"yeah, but I don't care about condvars"*. Well, for a pretty simple use case, not thinking about locking might be feasible, but then again for such simple use cases thinking about locking isn't a problem anyway...

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl ...To keep with your example, you may not want to think how many bytes `new MyObject` allocates, but you certainly need to think about that it at least allocates something that later needs to be `delete`d properly. Of course it could also just silenty allocate nothing and return a cached address to an already existing object and `delete`ing this was just a no-op. This would work in simple cases, until you have to *rely* on the fact that it really allocated some new storage (once you modify the pointed to object)...

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl ...The point of the existing answers is, that it is not a mere implementation detail if something is locked or not, but an important consideration to always keep in mind when messing with multiple threads (for the reasons given). Of course in very simple cases (which seem to be the ones you're after) you can just ignore it, but then those cases are too simple to just make this behaviour the **default**. Which in the end is the answer to your question. But like said you are free to have your own opinion on this and needn't accept the answerer's views and arguments.

Comment: Short simple rule, make your classes thread safe by only having instances touched by one thread. If you can't do that, reconsider your design. Then and only then consider synchronization. Often internal locks are the wrong answer from a complexity and performance standpoint.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Most of the time, if you think you need a recursive mutex then your design is wrong, so it definitely should not be the default.

For a class with a single mutex protecting the data members, then the mutex should be locked in all the `public` member functions, and all the `private` member functions should assume the mutex is already locked.

If a `public` member function needs to call another `public` member function, then split the second one in two: a `private` implementation function that does the work, and a `public` member function that just locks the mutex and calls the `private` one. The first member function can then also call the implementation function without having to worry about recursive locking.

e.g.

```
class X {
    std::mutex m;
    int data;
    int const max=50;

    void increment_data() {
        if (data >= max)
            throw std::runtime_error("too big");
        ++data;
    }
public:
    X():data(0){}
    int fetch_count() {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(m);
        return data;
    }
    void increase_count() {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(m);
        increment_data();
    } 
    int increase_count_and_return() {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(m);
        increment_data();
        return data;
    } 
};
```

This is of course a trivial contrived example, but the `increment_data` function is shared between two public member functions, each of which locks the mutex. In single-threaded code, it could be inlined into `increase_count`, and `increase_count_and_return` could call that, but we can't do that in multithreaded code.

This is just an application of good design principles: the public member functions take responsibility for locking the mutex, and delegate the responsibility for doing the work to the private member function.

This has the benefit that the `public` member functions only have to deal with being called when the class is in a consistent state: the mutex is unlocked, and once it is locked then all invariants hold. If you call `public` member functions from each other then they have to handle the case that the mutex is already locked, and that the invariants don't necessarily hold.

It also means that things like condition variable waits will work: if you pass a lock on a recursive mutex to a condition variable then (a) you need to use `std::condition_variable_any` because `std::condition_variable` won't work, and (b) only one level of lock is released, so you may still hold the lock, and thus deadlock because the thread that would trigger the predicate and do the notify cannot acquire the lock.

I struggle to think of a scenario where a recursive mutex is required.

Comment: my inner Herb asks shouldnt the mutex be mutable? :P second of all I see your point but from my point it actually says what I have been saying: you get nothing from using just mutex except joy of designing wrappers and thinking if you covered all the cases or not(might not be trivial in a bigger class). Not to mention that lock at beginning of every public method is much more KISS IMHO. Please dont get offended, I really respect your work on Boost and ISO, this is just like I said IMHO.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: in this example (which remember is "trivial" and "contrived"), the `fetch_count` function isn't marked `const`, so there's no benefit in marking the mutex `mutable`. If it was then there would be.

Comment: As @SteveJessop said, you only need `mutable` on your mutex if it can be used from a `const` member function. Also: the idea here **is** to "lock at the beginning of every public method" --- the distinction is that you don't call a public method from another one.

Comment: @AnthonyWilliams how would you document that in a code? I mean dont call public from public... just a comment? I dont trust ppl enough to enforce it just by comment:) Im not arguing against you I just wonder how would you document it cuz im curious.

Comment: One option is to extract a completely unsynchronized implementation class, so the class with the mutex has just 2 members - a mutex and the implementation class - and only public member functions, which lock the mutex and forward to the implementation class.

Comment: The other option is just to say "don't call a public member from another in a class with a mutex" and rely on people sticking to the rule. You'll soon get deadlock in testing if you don't!

Comment: My only worry is whether mutex per class instance is expensive. If the only actual resource is memory than 40 bytes seems like a fair price for simplicity of implementation and good thread properties. But I have no idea about details of the implementation.

Comment: "I struggle to think of a scenario where a recursive mutex is required". What about callbacks? Imaging a class that holds pointers to objects within a vector that needs to invoke a callback method on each of them. If that callback method invokes a public method of the original class that also uses the same lock (e.g. pop_back() on the vector) then here is your dead lock.

Comment: @Vassilis Yes, that will deadlock, so don't do that. Have the callbacks invoke a private member function that does what the public member function would, assuming the mutex is already locked (which it is). The public member function can just lock the mutex and call the new private member function.

Comment: To be honest, I would still use the recursive mutex instead of duplicating the methods like one for public and the other for private. As the others said, this cannot be the ultimate solution as you try to forbid calling public functions from each other. It is an obvious reason for a buggy code.

Answer (score 28):

> should `std::recursive_mutex` be default and `std::mutex` considered as an performance optimization?

Not really, no. The advantage of using non-recursive locks is *not* just a performance optimization, it means that your code is self-checking that leaf-level atomic operations really are leaf-level, they aren't calling something else that uses the lock.

There's a reasonably common situation where you have:

- a function that implements some operation that needs to be serialized, so it takes the mutex and does it.
- another function that implements a larger serialized operation, and wants to call the first function to do one step of it, while it is holding the lock for the larger operation.

For the sake of a concrete example, perhaps the first function atomically removes a node from a list, while the second function atomically removes *two* nodes from a list (and you never want another thread to see the list with only one of the two nodes taken out).

You don't *need* recursive mutexes for this. For example you could refactor the first function as a public function that takes the lock and calls a private function that does the operation "unsafely". The second function can then call the same private function.

However, sometimes it's convenient to use a recursive mutex instead. There's still an issue with this design: `remove_two_nodes` calls `remove_one_node` at a point where a class invariant doesn't hold (the second time it calls it, the list is in precisely the state we don't want to expose). But assuming we know that `remove_one_node` doesn't rely on that invariant this isn't a killer fault in the design, it's just that we've made our rules a little more complex than the ideal "all class invariants always hold whenever any public function is entered".

So, the trick is occasionally useful and I don't hate recursive mutexes to quite the extent that article does. I don't have the historical knowledge to argue that the reason for their inclusion in Posix is different from what the article says, "to demonstrate mutex attributes and thread extensons". I certainly don't consider them the default, though.

I think it's safe to say that if in your design you're uncertain whether you need a recursive lock or not, then your design is incomplete. You will later regret the fact that you're writing code and you *don't know* something so fundamentally important as whether the lock is allowed to be already held or not. So don't put in a recursive lock "just in case".

If you know that you need one, use one. If you know that you don't need one, then using a non-recursive lock isn't just an optimization, it's helping to enforce a constraint of the design. It's more useful for the second lock to fail, than for it to succeed and conceal the fact that you've accidentally done something that your design says should never happen. But if you follow your design, and never double-lock the mutex, then you'll never find out whether it's recursive or not, and so a recursive mutex isn't *directly* harmful.

This analogy might fail, but here's another way to look at it. Imagine you had a choice between two kinds of pointer: one that aborts the program with a stacktrace when you dereference a null pointer, and another one that returns `0` (or to extend it to more types: behaves as if the pointer refers to a value-initialized object). A non-recursive mutex is a bit like the one that aborts, and a recursive mutex is a bit like the one that returns 0. They both potentially have their uses -- people sometimes go to some lengths to implement a "quiet not-a-value" value. But in the case where your code is designed to never dereference a null pointer, you don't want to use *by default* the version that silently allows that to happen.

Comment: nice answer but I disagree with "something so fundamentally important as whether the lock is allowed to be already held or not. " tbh almost always I dont care if the lock is already held or not. I just want thread safety.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: so how do you avoid locking inversion, if you go around calling things willy-nilly with any old lock held? I suspect that actually you do care a bit ;-) Of course if there's only one lock that could be held then locking inversion isn't a risk: inversion is just one example of something that can go wrong if you don't design and document for what locks are allowed to be held when. Another example is if the inner function uses the mutex to wait on a condvar (releasing the lock) while the outer function really *doesn't* want the lock released.

Comment: @  Im talking here about class lvl mtx. Only one, so I just call it at the beginning of every public function. BTW sorry for not replying with @ SO autocomplete feature is broken for me ATM

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: A global lock per class, held by every function called on any instance of that class? Not scalable but yes, I suppose you would want it to be recursive. But what happens if you have two classes with such a lock, and there exists a function of class A that calls some function of class B, and in another thread another function of class B calls some function of class A? Deadlock. FYI, @ replies aren't necessary when addressing the author of the answer, and I believe SO silently removes them in an example of the "So Smug You Want To Slap It" UI design pattern.

Comment: per class instance. I hate statics , so I dont use them if they arent const:D

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: well then same issue but two objects, each of which operates on the other. The point is that internal locking does not work *in general*. Maybe it's OK for your class right now, but you can easily create situations where you need to acquire both locks at once. So you can't *in general* make a class thread-safe just by slapping a lock on it and taking the lock in every function.

Comment: then you can have external lock that the caller of the methods of the two classes owns. I mean from OO point of view you cant do anything about stuff outside your class(friendship ignored). Again I might be wrong, my OO skills are "skills"

Comment: "from OO point of view you cant do anything about stuff outside your class" You can do something about it, you can document the pre-conditions for your functions. So you would need to analyze and/or design your code in sufficient depth to identify when a caller needs to acquire both locks before calling your function. Once you understand the code to that depth, you can (if you choose) then design the recursive locks out of it, which is why non-recursive locks are a design decision and not (merely) a performance optimization.

Comment: tbh I have hard time imagining when me as a designer of class X should for example think about the way how class Z can use me and class Y in transactional way. Especially since it is not just class Y, it is all the possible classes that somebody might use "near" usage of X. in short as a designer of X I say:" not my problem". :)

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl Of course it's not your problem to fix each and every code using your class X. What is your problem is documenting class X in such a way that the outside user is aware of what problems can arise and how to fix them. This is why you have to document the locking intricacies of your class in some way or another, anyway. This is what *Steve*'s comment is about. Of course you could just drop any mutex and let the outside world care about the whole problem of synchronizing access, but from your question I would guess this in turn isn't your design goal.

Comment: @ChristianRau all I can do to help is to give them a way to lock me, right? But that sounds breakable... maybe have a friend that can lock me and they must create instance of that class that has ref to me and ref to where they want to copy me... but what I was talking here is: I want guarantee each single instance is thread safe, something like atomic<int> is atomic, but it doesnt mean that a3=a2+a1; is atomic in a sense that atomic doesnt imply transactions.

Answer (score 11):

I'm not going to directly weigh in on the mutex versus recursive_mutex debate, but I thought it would be good to share a scenario where recursive_mutex'es are absolutely critical to the design.

When working with Boost::asio, Boost::coroutine (and probably things like NT Fibers although I'm less familiar with them), it is absolutely essential that your mutexes be recursive even without the design problem of re-entrancy.

The reason is because the coroutine based approach by its very design will suspend execution *inside* a routine and then subsequently resume it. This means that two top level methods of a class might "be being called at the same time on the same thread" without any sub calls being made.

Answer (score 0):

I recently implemented something like this to do recursion w/o using `recursive_mutex`:

```
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct FakeLock{ FakeLock(std::mutex&){}}; // optimizes to nothing
using RealLock = std::lock_guard<std::mutex>;

class MyClass {
    public:
        template<bool LockMe = true>
        int factorial (int n) {
            // lock is only asserted when LockMe is true
            using Guard = std::conditional_t<LockMe, RealLock, FakeLock>;
            Guard lock(mutex_);
            int ans = 1;
            if (n > 0) {
                // make recursive call w/o asserting the lock
                ans =  n * factorial<false>(n-1);
            }
            return ans;
        }
    private:
        std::mutex mutex_;
};

int main () {
    MyClass wibble;
    int ten = 10;
    int big_number = wibble.factorial(ten);
    std::cout <<  ten << "! = " << big_number << std::endl;
}
```

output:

```
10! = 3628800
```