# Can a critical section object be stored in a std::vector?

Tags: winapi, move, stdvector, critical-section

According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-initializecriticalsection), a critical secion object cannot be copied or moved.

Does that imply it cannot be safely stored in a `std::vector` style collection as an instance?

Comment: I'm guessing this is not a C++ class? if it were it should have its copy/move ctors explicitly deleted.

Comment: sounds similar to a `std::mutex` (non-copyable and non-moveable) and an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16466170/2189130) indicates yes you *can* but you can't do anything that would potentially resize the vector (meaning you can only construct it with a fixed size)

Comment: also, `unique_ptr` might be an option to store references to these safely inside a `std::vector`

Comment: however, windows api structures are typically just declared as PODs which means you won't get a compiler error if you attempt to copy or move it :/

Comment: @BradAllred it's part of a C API

Comment: i be first ask - what sense at all store it in `std::vector` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct; the `CRITICAL_SECTION` object should not be copied/moved as it may stop working (E.g. perhaps it contains pointers to itself).

One approach would be to store a vector of smart pointers, e.g. (C++17 code):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

using CS_ptr = std::unique_ptr<CRITICAL_SECTION, decltype(&DeleteCriticalSection)>;

CS_ptr make_CriticalSection(void)
{
    CS_ptr p(new CRITICAL_SECTION, DeleteCriticalSection);
    InitializeCriticalSection(p.get());
    return p;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<CS_ptr> vec;
    vec.push_back( make_CriticalSection() );    
}
```

---

Consider using `std::recursive_mutex` which is a drop-in replacement for CRITICAL SECTION (and probably just wraps it in a Windows implementation), and performs the correct initialization and release in its destructor.

Standard mutexes are also non-copyable so for this case you'd use `std::unique_ptr<std::recursive_mutex>` if you wanted a vector of them.

[As discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14498892/stdmutex-vs-stdrecursive-mutex-as-class-member) also consider whether you actually want `std::mutex` instead of a recursive mutex.

NOTE: Windows `Mutex` is an inter-process object; `std::mutex` and friends correspond to a `CRITICAL_SECTION`.

---

I would also suggest reconsidering the need for a vector of mutexes; there may be a better solution to whatever you're trying to do.