# Is there any way I can make my program panic rather than deadlock if I have lock a mutex twice in one thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21892934/how-to-assert-if-a-stdmutex-is-locked), I learned the following:

1. I can inherit from `std::mutex`, and check if `m_holder` equals to the current thread id. I think the way is kind of hack, since it is considered a [bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806173/subclass-inherit-standard-containers) to inherit from std class. Moreover, `m_holder` is some implementation of some C++ library which is not a standard interface
2. I can use `owns_lock` of `unique_lock`. However, it is a bad idea, since the method only checks if the current lock holds the mutex. We don't use `unique_lock` in this way.
3. A `recursive_mutex` can save us from deadlock when we double lock a mutex in a thread. However, we must firstly check our code design [before we decide that we really need to use this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14498892/stdmutex-vs-stdrecursive-mutex-as-class-member). However, I think I have a good design. What I need is a runtime check that if a certain mutex is locked twice by a thread, it will crash rather than dead lock. So a `recursive_mutex` seems not suitable for me.

Comment: I think you mentioned the solution in step 3. Make sure the threading design is sound, based on a locking strategy that is chosen up front (you can't come in after the fact an shoehorn thread safety in, specially not with deadlocks in place). Option4 : if performance/latency isn't your biggest problem : use an executor (dispatcher), that has a queue of tasks (lambdas) and executes functions one by one in the code that needs to be threadsafe. And don't be too spooked by deadloack, you can debug them I prefer them over race conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ways to have your cake and eat it with the first solution.
We could achieve exactly the same result if we wrapped the `std::mutex` as a member instead of inheriting from it:

```cpp
class mutex
{
    std::mutex m_mutex;
    std::atomic<std::thread::id> m_holder = std::thread::id{};

public:
    void lock()
    {
        // TODO: if we wanted to, we could check locked_by_caller()
        //       and panic if true
        m_mutex.lock();
        m_holder = std::this_thread::get_id(); 
    }
    
    bool try_lock()
    {
        if (m_mutex.try_lock()) {
            m_holder = std::this_thread::get_id();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    void unlock()
    {
        m_mutex.unlock();
    }

    bool locked_by_caller() const
    {
        return m_holder == std::this_thread::get_id();
    }
};
```

*Original code provided by [@AmiTavory](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3510736/ami-tavory) at https://stackoverflow.com/a/30109512/5740428*

> Moreover, `m_holder` is some implementation of some C++ library which is not a standard interface

No, you've misunderstood the original code. `m_holder` is a member we defined ourselves. We're not relying on any particular standard library implementation. In general, standard library members are named something like `_M_holder` to use reserved names which can't be replaced by macros.

Comment: I think this is a good debugging aid. If OP has multiple mutexes involved in a deadlock the panic code will still not trigger. However it can be used to analyze which threads hold which locks (if the debug build does not already supports this)